# Как получить входные данные из блокнота переменной длины Python

Tags: python

Необходимо забрать данные из файла. Проблема в том, что числа могут быть различной длины. Написал такой код, но он работает только с целым числом, состоящим из одной цифры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
data = open("input.txt", encoding="utf-8")
n = 0
list_value = []
while n <= 6:
    rows = data.readline()
    print(rows[0])
    list_value.append(rows[0])
    n = n + 1
list_value = [int(x) for x in list_value]
print(list)
```

Comment: Используйте `rows.split()[0]` вместо `rows[0]` и `float` вместо `int`

Comment: Спасибо)) Помогло.